# PHP refresh a page which has '?var=value'

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to refresh the page right after the query is executed.  The page was able to display the pop-up message "Successful". However, it was not able to refresh the page properly and only display pop-up message infinitely. The current page url is `http://localhost/test/test.php?post=1`

```
<form method="post"  role="form" action="reply.php">  
    <fieldset>
     <div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="reply" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Comment" required autofocus=""></textarea>
     </div>         
     <button name="post" type="submit" class="[ btn btn-success ]" data-loading-text="Loading...">Post reply</button>
      </fieldset>
</form>
```

## reply.php

```
 if (isset($_POST['post'])) {             
                $description =$_POST['reply'];  
                $stmt = "INSERT INTO reply (comments) VALUES (:description)";
                $p = $MySQLi_CON -> prepare($stmt);

                $results = $p -> execute(array(
                ":description" => $description
                ));
              echo '<script language = "javascript">';
              echo 'alert("Successful")';
              echo '</script>';
              echo  "<script> location.reload(true); </script>";

                if(!$results){
                      echo '<script language = "javascript">';
                      echo 'alert("Fail")';
                      echo '</script>';
                      echo  "<script> location.reload(true); </script>";            
                }           
    }
```

Comment: Why not using pup header instant of JavaScript ?! Just use : header('location: URL to same page'); Or you can use jQuery with Ajax which is also a better solution then using JavaScript inside PHP !

Comment: I am trying to locate to the same page which is http://localhost/test/test.php?post=1 . If i tried that method, it only goes to http://localhost/test/test.php

Comment: And who said that ?! you can use whatever you want in the URL of a header ! just use : header('location:  localhost/test/test.php?post=1');

Comment: I tried that, it works that way because test.php?post=1 is '?var=value'. The URL is not fixed though :/

Comment: So use your value ! lol :D it's PHP, you can use the variable every where you like :) use your variable as it is in your URL inside the header :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this code

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['post'])) {
            $description =$_POST['reply'];
            $stmt = "INSERT INTO reply (comments) VALUES (:description)";
            $p = $MySQLi_CON -> prepare($stmt);

            $results = $p -> execute(array(
            ":description" => $description
            ));
         header('Location: http://localhost/test/test.php?post=1'); exit();
}
?>
```

you can also use this code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['post'])) {
$description = $_POST['reply'];
$stmt = "INSERT INTO reply (comments) VALUES (:description)";
$p = $MySQLi_CON->prepare($stmt);

$results = $p->execute(array(
    ":description" => $description
));
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
exit();
 }
?>
```

Comment: I tried header('Location: http://localhost/test/test.php') but the test.php?post=1 is '?var=value'. The URL is not fixed. 1 is the value of the post_ID

Comment: @fypforstack that's basically what I said :)

Comment: @soheyl 
but i may have for instance. I just want to refresh the current page I am at
 test.php?post=1
 test.php?post=2
 test.php?post=3

Comment: check my update answer . it will work also and no need fixed url

Comment: @fypforstack The updated answer should resolve ur problem anyway :)

Comment: @Soheyl thanks, that solved my problem right away :)